# Не могу вывести переменную char

Tags: c++, winforms

У меня есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую, слово должно шифроваться Цезарем и выводиться в textBox3, но слово нельзя вывести из-за "отсутствия операнда "+" ", но указатель выводится. В чём проблема?

```
   private: System::Void button1_Click_2(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    char buffer[256]; int shift = Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
        buffer[i] += shift;
    textBox3->Text += "\r\n Слово: " + buffer;

}
```

Comment: Функция `strlen` работает только с `c`-строками, а не с неинициализированными массивами.

Comment: значит нужно преобразовать char в string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то тут всё наперекосяк.

- У вас в буфере нет строки - какие именно данные вы сдвигаете?
- Почему конвертация в `double`, а потом сразу приведение типа к `int`?
- `strlen(buffer)` работает, если там есть какие-то данные, ограниченные 0. Если в этом случайном наборе байтов нет 0, то это - выход за пределы массива.
- в шифре Цезаря сдвиг циклический, а не просто увеличить всё на какое-то число, как в этом коде - вы получите абракадабру
- операции `+`, `+=` есть у объектов типа `string`. Создайте объекты `string` из строк  - `textBox3->Text += string("\r\n Слово: ") + string(buffer);`

```
{
    char buffer[256];  // создан пустой буфер - без данных
    int shift = Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text); // конвертация в `double` и приведение типа к `int` по-умолчанию
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++) // в буфере неизвестные данные
        buffer[i] += shift;
    textBox3->Text += "\r\n Слово: " + buffer;
}
```

Comment: Напортачил сильно, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя складывать C-строки, нужно чтобы хотя бы одна была типа std::string

```
textBox3->Text += "\r\n Слово: " + std::string(buffer);
```

Comment: ну... теперь жалуется на +=, есть ещё какая-то причина, по которой нельзя вывести /shrug

Comment: попробуй System::String(buffer)